# mongodb query using $in for list of lists

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document as:

```
{
    'name':'XYZ',
    'address':'Street 21',
    'phone': {
        'home': [123456, 456123]
    },
    'qualification': {
        'primary': [
            ['AB','75'],
            ['CD','80'],
            ['EF','50']
        ]
    }
}
```

Simple query would be like:

```
n = collection.find({'name':'XYZ'})
```

I can fetch documents using a list on the `'phone.home'` subdocument key like this:

```
list1 = [123456]
n = collection.find({'phone.home':{'$in': list1}})
```

I am stuck on how to query the collection using the `qualification` key. Suppose I have either 'AB' or '75' (only one of them at a time),  I am not able to make up query, e.g I only have the following list1:

```
list1 = ['AB']

n = collection.find({'qualification.primary':{'$in':list1}})
```

This definitely is not giving me the desired result. Any guidance will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) two times query as :

```js
db.collectionName.find(
    {
      "qualification.primary":{ "$elemMatch": { "$elemMatch":{ "$in": ["AB"] }}}
    },
    { "qualification.primary.$":1 }
)
```